# Use of lambda expression in C++ ternary operator : error type mismatch

Tags: c++11, lambda, conditional-operator

I am just exploring lambda expression and trying to use it to return from a function using C++ ternary operator. However the below code does not work with error!

**this is a simplified version of the program to explain my actual problem so kindly post answer using a lambda only, not just return (x+y+offset).**

> In member function 'int Calculator::add(int, int)': 12:26: error: no
> match for ternary 'operator?:' (operand types are 'bool', 'int', and
> 'Calculator::add(int, int)::<lambda()>') 16:3: warning: control
> reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    
    class Calculator
    {
      public:
      bool initalized = false;
      int offset = 0;
      
      int add(int x, int y)
      {
          return !initalized ? -1 : [this, x, y]()
          {
              return ((x+y) + offset);
          };
      }
    };
    
    int main()
    {
        Calculator c;
        c.initalized = true;
        c.offset = 1;
    
        printf("%d", c.add(2,10));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to call the lambda, -1 and lambda doesn't have a common type

Comment: can u pls show me through code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ternary operator tries to return -1 or a lambda, which do not have a common type.

You need to actually call the lambda:

```
return !initalized ? -1 : [this, x, y]()
      {
          return ((x+y) + offset);
      }(); // <= added ()
```

Or without a lambda:

```
return !initalized ? -1 : x+y+offset;
```

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong here?

The true/false parts of the ternary expression are not compatible. You cannot convert `-1` to a lambda expression and you cannot convert the lambda expression to an `int`.

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do with the lambda expression but it can be:

```
return !initalized ? -1 : (x + y + this->offset);
```

If you have the need to use a lambda expression for some reason, you'll have to invoke the lambda expression.

```
return !initalized ? -1 : [this, x, y]() { return ((x+y) + this->offset); }();
//                                                                 missing ^^
```

Comment: This is understood, I am written a simplified program to mimic by actual problem. How someone can do it by using lambda function is my question!